# Pole Display clear text

Tags: c#, text

I able to send a text to COM1 by using

```
serialPort1.Write("Hello World");
```

but how to clear all the displayed text and start a new text? Im using VFD-800 :)

Comment: i read the class from here, but seems nothing is helpng :( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx

Comment: Once data leaves your serial port you have no control over it - whatever the receiving device chooses to do with it, that's it's decision. I think you need to read the manual for VFD-800; in there you'll probably find something like esacpe sequences to do particular tasks eg... clear the screen. So you would write that sequence to the serial port, and the VFD-800 would then clear the screen for you

Comment: i found a manual here.
http://support.j2rs.com/Docs/VFD%20Pole%20Display.pdf
but i duno how to use the ESC code at c#, can guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page 30 of the manual you've linked to contains a command of CLR which will "clear display screen and clear string mode".

To do this you need to send Hex code 0C.

A link on how to send hex codes down a serial line:

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=509359

You'll also want to look up the other codes you'll probably need like positioning your cursor.